# mysql innodb problem

Tags: mysql, innodb

seeing the following in my mysql error log file:

```
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 5242880 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 268435456 bytes!
110927 18:36:37 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
110927 18:36:37 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
```

How can this be easily fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: ll -h | grep ib
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 4.1G Sep 27 13:50 ibdata1
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 5.0M Sep 27 13:50 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 5.0M Sep 26 11:45 ib_logfile1

Comment: tried:  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13494

Comment: mysqld is not starting up....   just seeing Starting MySQL........

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, in your my.cnf you must have innodb_log_file_size= 256M.

So stop your MYSQL server, rename the ib_logfile0 & ib_logfile1 files, then restart your server. It should create two new files each 256M in size.

How you got into this situation is an important question. Trying to restore an old backup? i.e. Before the innodb_log_file_size was changed in your my.cnf.

Comment: This is pretty much the answer. What took so long for anyone to upvote this (Rhetorical) ??? +1 !!!